# Calling a controller function using javascript onchange event in zend

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, onchange

I have an select dropdown list on my view

```
        <?php $level = $this->escapeHtml($user->level); ?>

        <?php if ($level == 1): ?>
             <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
             <option value="2">Manager</option>
             <option value="3">HR Staff</option>
         <?php elseif ($level == 2): ?>
             <option value="1" >Administrator</option>
             <option value="2" selected="selected">Manager</option>
             <option value="3">HR Staff</option>
           <?php elseif ($level == 3): ?>
             <option value="1" >Administrator</option>
             <option value="2" >Manager</option>
             <option value="3" selected="selected">HR Staff</option>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </select>
```

and it has an onchange event that calls this javascript function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function changeLevel(obj){

}

</script>
```

and on my controller i have this function

```
 public function editLevel()
    {
> updating level code here.
    }
```

What i want is every onchange in my view, i will call my editLevel function in my controller. how can i call a controller function using a javascript onchange? thanks in advance!

Comment: Use AJAX to call this as it would be normal page (eg. `/cms/edit`)

Comment: Thanks, but kindly give me some idea what this look like? and how can I pass my parameters into it?

Comment: Where is the value of $level coming from? Database? Would you like to update the database each time user changes value in the drop-down.

Comment: The value of $level will be coming from the value of the selected dropdown. YES thats what i need to do.

Comment: Ajax using jQuery with good examples - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/